# Como se lee este codigo?

Tags: python, string, bucle-for, bucles

Como se lee este codigo? Necesito entenderlo, pero me confunde el for.. Gracias.

```
def consonantes():
    palabra = input("Ingrese una palabra: ").lower()
    vocales = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    for letra in vocales:
        palabra = palabra.replace(letra, "")
        print(palabra)
```

consonantes()

Comment: ¿Qué te confunde del `for`? Explica cómo lo entiendes. Lee [ask]. Además, ¿probaste ejecutar el código paso a paso para entender su funcionamiento?

Comment: Siento decirte que tu respuesta es demasiado sencilla y acabara cerrada. Es un problema de comprensión. Te dejo un [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQGhU1526Oo&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BlvPxziopYZRd55pdqFwkeS&index=14) de YouTube que lo explica. Haz caso a @padaleiana . Espero ayudarte.

Comment: @nadie las preguntas cuyas respuestas serían  "sencillas"  no acaban cerradas. Lo que si concuerdo que quizá este sitio no sea el adecuado para este tipo de dudas.

Comment: Ingresa una palabra y elimina todas sus vocales.

Comment: Me parece que probablemente quiso decir "pregunta", no "respuesta" @DanteS. Pero sí, concuerdo. Debe ser un problema _específico_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te daré un ejemplo:
Palabra = murcielago

```
for letra in vocales:
```

Significa que hará 1 recorrido por cada elemento en "vocales" que tiene 5 elementos (a, e, i, o, u) y en cada recorrido "letra" tomará cada valor en vocales (a, e, i, o, u), recorrido 1 "letra = a"... recorrido 5 "letra = u"

```
palabra = palabra.replace(letra, "")
```

Se reemplazará en "murcielago" (palabra) el elemento "letra" (que en el primer recorrido vale = "a") por "", osea se borrará la letra "a",
ejm: murcielgo, ahora esta resultado se volverá la variable "palabra", aquí termina 1 ciclo y falta 4 más, en cada ciclo irán quitando cada una de las vocales (murcilgo, murclgo, murclg, mrclg) y se guardará como nueva variable, al terminar el último ciclo te debe quedar así : mrclg

Answer (score 2):

Primero el codigo recibe el input del usuario, luego este se pone en minuscula y se guarda en una variable palabra. Despues, se crea una lista con las vocales (esto servirá para el for). Luego, se crea un for letra in vocales, esto crea una iteración en cada elemento de la lista, ver imagen. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Es decir cada vez que se corre el for, letra tendra un valor diferente de vocales, primero será vocales[0], luego vocales[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwfEv.png) y asi. Teniendo en cuenta esto al final el .replace cambia la vocal seleccionada por "", es decir, por espacio en blanco, la elimina. Este codigo no es la mejor solución para eliminar las variables, sin embargo, ahi esta la explicación. Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo!